# Center position CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with CSS styles. I want to set center position of my modal but i can't and i don't know exactly how to make that. Also I don't know how to make smaller modal size.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

.video-container {
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:56.25%;
    padding-top:30px;
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.video-container iframe, .video-container object, .video-container embed {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e4/Small-city-symbol.svg/348px-Small-city-symbol.svg.png" id="myBtn" class="image fit" alt="" />
 <div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h2>Header</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
   <br />
   <br />
   <div class="video-container"><iframe width="100" height="100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LRblJyq_4Ko?rel=0?ecver=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I want to make always the modal on the center and to be scaled. The bottom can't be longer than screen size.

Comment: I tried running your snippet. changing the `width` from `80%` to `60%` in `.modal-content` class reduces the modal size and including `margin-top: -3%`  in `.modal` class makes it go above and get centred over. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

@Oliwier, Can you please elaborate the question?
My understanding is that from your question and the comment,
is that, 
You are looking to reduce the size of the video and want to center it.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

.video-container {
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:56.25%;
    padding-top:30px;
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.video-container iframe, .video-container object, .video-container embed {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.container{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;

  display: block;
}
.image{
 display:block;
 margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class ="container">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e4/Small-city-symbol.svg/348px-Small-city-symbol.svg.png" id="myBtn" class="image fit" alt="" /></div>
 <div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h2>Header</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
   <br />
   <br />
   <div class="video-container"><iframe width="100" height="100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LRblJyq_4Ko?rel=0?ecver=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Nope. You Centered the black button. What they want is that their modal size be smaller and shouldn't be longer than the screen size.